# Android- ArrayAdapter constructor

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am going through this tutorial on Android here
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDebugging/article.html

And in the exercise it gives some code with a fault. It says the problem is in here

```
public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, List<String> values) {
   super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
   this.context = context;
   this.values = values;
}
```

This is a constructor for a defined class MyArrayAdapter that extends ArrayAdapter. The tutorial says that the call constructor for the super class ArrayAdpater is wrong. Well I tried debugging it, I don't see what the problem is. Any insight, maybe I don't understand the ArrayAdapter concept well.

Comment: refer this http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/how-to-create-a-listview-using-arrayadapter-in-android/..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor is wrong

```
public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, List<String> values) {
```

Look at the [ArrayAdapter Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and there is no constructor which takes these arguments

Probably the simplest is to use this constructor

> ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects)

and add your `layout` file for the other parameter. Also, change your `super` call accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, List<String> values) {
   super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values); // change here
   this.context = context;
   this.values = values;
}
```